# Indexing Arrays in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

New Here. I have a 100x100x100 array. I want to select only the first 10x10x10 values in the array, then average across first two dimensions for a 100x10 array. Then I need to pull out 20 of the values from the 100x10 and plot those 20 numbers on a scatterplot. Any help?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: With the advice given by @yatu we could help you better. In addition, I recommend you to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please clarify two points about your question:  Let's assume the 100x100x100 is `x = np.ones((100,100,100))` for the moment, and then the first 10x10x10 block is `y = x[:10,:10,:10]`.  No problem.  But (1) I have no idea how any average of a 10x10x10 matrix can result in a 100x10 matrix and (2) what are the x and y coordinates of the 20 numbers? their indices in the 100x10?

Comment: So I was just told to make a 100x100x100 array of random numbers (I used np.random.rand(100,100,100)). (1.) I am not sure about the 100x10 matrix so we can disregard that step. (2.) I guess the x and y coordinates are simply random? Can be any indices in the 100x10? Thanks so much I am brand new to Python!